# PHP passthru: unable to get full response from python script

Tags: php, python, response, passthru

I'm trying to get data from Python script:

```
import pymorphy2
import json
import sys

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
butyavka = morph.parse(sys.argv[1])[0]
for item in butyavka.lexeme:
    print(item.word)
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
chdir('C:\\Users\Michael-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32');
$out;
passthru('python WordAnalizator.py "слово"', $out);
echo($out);
?>
```

If I use console, it make correct response, like:

[image]

But in PHP I have only first word:

[image]

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obvious encoding problem (Russian letters become unreadable). So, try to set (i.e. change default) encoding in the PHP code, e.g. add to header usage of Unicode:

```
 header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If `charset=utf-8` does not help, try `charset=windows-1251` instead.

**UPDATE:**

Do not forget to save your file (PHP code in UTF encoding for utf-8, or ANSI for windows-1251)